Nuxt Vercel Deployment Failing
Worth a shot asking here. I am having trouble deploying my Nuxt app onto Vercel for some strange reason, I can't pinpoint the error. When I deploy, everything seems fine in the deployment script, but when I go to the runtime logs, I see this:
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot find module 
'/var/task/node_modules/global/window' imported from /var/task/chunks/build/server.mjs
 Did you mean to import "global/window.js"?
 at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:269:11)  
 at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:937:10)  
 at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1161:14)  
 at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1204:79)  
 at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)  
 at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)  
 at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)  
 at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)  
 at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

My application works fine locally, and also here is my package json if it helps somehow.
{
 "name": "nuxt-app",
 "private": true,
 "type": "module",
 "scripts": {
 "build": "nuxt build",
 "dev": "nuxt dev",
 "generate": "nuxt generate",
 "preview": "nuxt preview",
 "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
},
 "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.569.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.569.0",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@tanstack/vue-query": "^5.32.1",
    "@videojs-player/vue": "^1.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "next-auth": "4.21.1",
    "nuxt": "3.12.3",
    "nuxt-mongoose": "^1.0.5",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "v-calendar": "next",
    "video.js": "^8.12.0",
    "vue": "3.4.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
},
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.2.0",
    "@sidebase/nuxt-auth": "^0.7.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.7"
  }
}

Yeah. If anyone has any clue or idea to lead me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you!

I have the same issue here, whereas the import paths are correct and everything works fine in local, and during build preview with nitro node preset.
